# 1000 people and the number 105

Tags: probability

If $1000$ people randomly select an integer between $1$ and $500$ (inclusive), calculate
the probability that precisely three of those people select the number $105$?

Comment: Catherine, welcome to Math.SE. Please show your work on the problem and we will gladly help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

- What is the probability one person will select 105? Call this $p$.
- Now you have the same experiment repeated independently 1000 times with probability of success $p$. What is the probability that you get exactly 3 successes? (Do you know about the Binomial distribution? If not, how many ways are there to get 3 successes out of 1000 identical trials?)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Give the persons a number.

The probability that persons $1,2,3$
choose for $105$ and the others do not is $\left(\frac{1}{500}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{499}{500}\right)^{997}$.

There are more options however.

Also, for instance, the persons with
numbers $6,555,786$ can choose for $105$ while the others don't.
Any idea how much options there are?

Comment: 1000 factorial?

Comment: i tried the calculation you've written above and multiplied it by 1000!/3!*997! but my calculator can't handle the size of the numbers

Comment: Your try is okay, but you do not even need your calculator for it. This because $\frac{1000!}{997!}=1000\times999\times998$

Comment: @Catherine: You've picked just the right number to multiply by. Well done!